# Unable to debug app service in azure: MSVSMON does not appear to be running

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, botframework, remote-debugging

I am developing a web app bot in azure and I am having trouble remote debugging it using VS 2017. The debugging worked for me before (I used Server explorer > MyResourceGroup > app service > attach debugger), but now all of a sudden it doesn't, showing the following error:

[image]

I have verified the debugging settings in the azure portal for the app service:

[image]

Also tried restarting the service, switching off and turning back on debugging option in azure. Please help fix this debugging issue, not having it makes development very hard.

**UPDATE 1:** Logged into Kudu, confirmed that MSVSMON is running:
[image]

Comment: Common issue, they dedicated an [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/unable-to-connect-to-the-microsoft-visual-studio-remote-debugging-monitor) to help troubleshoot this.

Comment: @HansPassant, looked at the doc, but it doesn't seem to be specific to azure debugging, which might be important here, as I cannot remote into the machine.

Comment: You can try to remote debug another Azure web app and check if same issue appears. Or you can publish your bot application to another app service and try to attach debugger to that new app service.